# Using .Dispose in a thread safe way

Tags: c#, event-handling, thread-safety, dispose

In a previous question I was given an awesome solution to a memory leak issue I was experiencing. There is one problem though- the solution involves disposing of unnecessary data in an event handler that appears to be being called before its last iteration has finished. Every time a new frame is pulled from my webcam, it calls this event handler.

```
    private void Handle_New_Frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //textBox1.Text = "Frame #: " + counter;
        //counter++;

        //bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        if (bitmap != null)
            bitmap.Dispose();
        bitmap = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);

        //bitmap = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(eventArgs.Frame);


        if (videoPictureBox1.Image != null)
            videoPictureBox1.Dispose(); //THE CRASH HAPPENS HERE. 
        videoPictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    }
```

The error is: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'videoPictureBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

My problem is that I am not at all familiar with C# threading, and not in a comfortable place with threading in general. I have found similar questions on StackOverflow but none that I was able to pull enough information relating to my own issue to put me on the right track (or maybe I looked right at the answer and missed it!)

I found two MSDN answers in the links below, but I'm still having a bit of a difficult time grasping what solution would be the most suitable for my issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28EHInvalidOperation.WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8843a9ch.aspx

I apologize for asking two questions in such short succession, and also for them being on the same topic. I'm just afraid without a nudge in the proper direction, I might flail around like a fish out of water on google for a while, looking at the wrong places.

So my question: What method do you think would be best suited to avoid this error? If you happen to know of documentation, sample code or a tutorial that would help me figure this out, that too would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Just google for `cross thread ui access`. SO is full of answers

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that!

Comment: so far I haven't had much luck finding a thread safe implementation of dispose >_>

Comment: Are you sure you want to dispose `videoPictureBox1`? The very next line uses it...

Comment: Basic guidelines to stay out of trouble: you will need to make a deep copy of the bitmap since the original is usually only temporary.  Don't use Clone(), use the Bitmap(Image) constructor.  Use the BeginInvoke() method to update the picturebox, don't forget to dispose the old Image property or you'll run out of memory.  If your UI freezes then the camera is sending bitmaps faster than you can display them.

Comment: HAH! David- I forgot to put the .Image after that. I appreciate you pointing that. Still have the cross-threading issue, but that was a stupid mistake that needed to be fixed lol

Comment: @HansPassant: What would you think of having a callback the UI could use at any time to take a snapshot of the currently-loaded picture; one could then specify that the UI would be responsible for disposing the snapshot it had asked for.  Everything UI-side would be on the UI thread, and if the picture changes multiple times without the UI getting a chance to display it, the versions that didn't get shown wouldn't have to get copied.  A reference to the current picture should be stored in its own object which should be locked when the picture is changing or a UI thread is copying it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Since changing the picture shouldn't take long, and the old one could be disposed after the lock was released, the only way a UI thread could be blocked at the lock for any significant time would be if multiple windows with different UI threads wanted to use the same picture source.  In that scenario, each UI thread could have to wait while others copied the picture.  Unless there were an absurd number of such windows, however, UI response should not be a problem even then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be disposing your videopicturebox if you are still using it.  You should only dispose resources that are not needed anymore.

Your code should be something like this

```
private void Handle_New_Frame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var newBitmap = new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame);
    //This assumes the picture box descends from Control
    if(videoPictureBox1.InvokeRequired)        
    {
        Action action = () => videoPictureBox1.Image = newBitmap;
        //Invoke to make the action happen on the GUI thread
        videoPictureBox1.Invoke(action);
    }
    else
        videoPictureBox1.Image = newBitmap;    
    //Dispose the old bitmap now that it is not assigned to the picturebox anymore   
    if (bitmap != null)
        bitmap.Dispose();
    bitmap = newBitmap;
}
```

You could also split the logic out into another method and then Invoke that method or not depending on if the Invoke is required.

Comment: I think the code needs a `try/catch` around the invoke, since there's no other nice way to guard against the possibility that someone might try to close the form containing `videoPictureBox` might get disposed just as you're wanting to update it.  In many cases that would be a perfectly legitimate usage scenario; it irks me that there are no `TryInvoke` and `TryBeginInvoke` methods to deal with it in sane fashion.